# Error recovery and parse trees in Anltr4

Tags: parsing, error-handling, antlr4

Is it possible to instruct the error recover mechanism from Antlr4 to build an empty tree for a given rule with errors?

I don't want to lose the whole parse tree but only the subtrees with respect to the root rule with parsing issues.

If we have something like:

```
ruleA : ruleB | ruleC;
ruleB : something
      | somethingElse;
ruleC: ...;
```

If subrule `something` throws a NoViableAltException for instance, then I don't want the parse tree for ruleB.

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you not control the subtree for a rule, but it's not even possible to influence the parser construction anywhere. Depending on the lookahead and where the error is it can happen that such an error makes the entire parse run fail and returning an empty parse tree, even though much of the input would match.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, is there a way to visit a parse tree and remove the sub-trees with missing tokens? And the result of that visitor would be a new parse tree.

Comment: Or is even a way to know if a given rule has missing tokens?

Comment: No, how can you know what doesn't exist? The runtime is not designed to do this kind of tree processing and seriously: why would you do that at all? When you walk the tree and find things you don't need, why first removing it instead of doing the real processing, ignoring the things you don't need?